# How can make int val[100000000] array?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
  int val[100000000] ;
  printf("%d", CHAR_BIT);
}
```

When I execute the code, It occur "segment fault" error. I suppose this error mean that there is no enough memory on the heap area.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not the *heap* that's the problem, it's the *stack*.  You've declared a local variable, and local variables live on the stack.

Try `int *val = malloc(sizeof(int)*100000000);` instead.  You can test whether that succeeds by examining whether `(val != NULL)`.

(Of course, you'll need to remember to call `free(val)` when you're done with the memory.)

Comment: As an alternative, the array can be declared static.  Then he doesn't have to worry about remembering to free it.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays are allocated on the stack. Try using the heap with `malloc` instead.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the stack size of a thread is probably about 2 megabytes. You've tried to allocate more than that on the stack, which causes an error.

Depending on your platform, you may be able to change the default stack size allocation with the `--stack` option to `ld`, but that's not recommended. It's preferable in your case to use `malloc()`. The stack should not normally be used to store large data structures.